# Simple Javascript XML Slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I just have two simple functions: one that loads the image into an img node, and one that pluses an i variable. The second function fires after a timer event, + the count, and then fires the image() function again. Except it's not working.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    //XML Loaded, create the slideshow
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var slideShow = document.getElementById('slideShow');
    var items = [];
    var nl = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('image');
    var i = 0;
    var t;

    function image() {
        var slideShowImg = document.getElementById('slideShowImg');
        var nli = nl.item(i);
        var src = nli.getAttribute('src').toString();
        var width = parseInt(nli.getAttribute('width').toString());
        var height = parseInt(nli.getAttribute('height').toString());

        var imgNode = document.createElement('img');
        imgNode.setAttribute('src', src);
        imgNode.setAttribute('height', height);
        imgNode.setAttribute('width', width);
        slideShowImg.appendChild(imgNode);

        t = setTimeout("nextImage()", 5000);
    }

    function nextImage() {
        i++;
        image();
    }

    image();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks very suspicious:

```
t = setTimeout("nextImage()", 5000);
```

Try this instead:

```
t = setTimeout(nextImage, 5000);
```

Comment: Under normal circumstances, both would work.  However, I've a feeling that nextImage as a string means you're looking in the top-level scope for the function, and the nextImage routine goes out of scope before it's called.  If you'd used the symbol name (and possibly defined the function above the place where it's called) you'd have been good.

Comment: The difference is that you can have a scoping problem with the first, since it may not be able to access the function in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Move the function definitions out of the if statement.

Comment: Otherwise nextImage() will not be found.

Comment: Precisely the reverse solution to the John Fisher's answer.  Both will work.